# Compose dark mode never shows dark colors

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

So I used https://m3.material.io/theme-builder#/custom to create a theme, I downloaded it, and I'm using it. But it only ever shows light colors.

`AppTheme.kt`

```
@Composable
fun AppTheme(
  useDarkTheme: Boolean = isSystemInDarkTheme(),
  content: @Composable() () -> Unit
) {
  val colors = if (!useDarkTheme) {
    LightColors
  } else {
    DarkColors
  }

  MaterialTheme(
    colorScheme = colors,
    content = content
  )
}
```

`MainActivity.kt`

```
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onStart() {
        super.onStart()
        Koin.init(context = this)
    }
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            val navController = rememberNavController()
            AppTheme(useDarkTheme = true) {
                NavHost(
                    navController = navController,
                    startDestination = Screen.Home.route
                ) {
                    addHomeTopLevel(navController)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

`HomeScreen.kt`

```
@Composable
fun HomeScreen(
    navController: NavController
) {
    val viewModel: HomeViewModel by inject(HomeViewModel::class.java)

    HomeContent()
}

@Composable
private fun HomeContent() {
    Scaffold(
        backgroundColor = MaterialTheme.colors.background,
        topBar = {
            TopAppBar {
                Text("Hello World!")
            }
        },
        content = {
            Text("Hello Wolrd")
        }
    )
}
```

My emulator is in dark mode, but it's still showing light colors. The color values are correct, and they're part of `LightColors` and `DarkColors` correctly. The boolean is correct, and even if I change both to `DarkColors` it still shows light ones.

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here.

Comment: Are you using the Scaffold from Material3? You could be importing the legacy Material composables.

Comment: Like @Francesc just said you are using the old Material 2 theme for you background. The new is called `MaterialTheme.colorScheme` not `MaterialTheme.colors`.